# General type of Postfix mail configuration

Tags: debian, postfix

During Postfix installation I configured `General type of mail configuration`.

How check this configuration after intallation?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it.  Service a real domain on the internet? Relay from your LAN to a ISP SMTP server? Local mail only?  Fake domain for local testing?

Comment: I just typed `sudo apt-get install postfix`. I choosed `Internet Site`, then I typed my mail system name and that's all for now. I just want be sure that I choosed `Internet site` properly. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the default install and config will often end up in what was considered a "working system" 15+ years ago, to actually run an Internet connected mail server today requires a little more diligence and set up.

You'll want to ensure that you do not have an open relay, that you have SPF and/or DKIM records that are properly configured, proper MX entries in your DNS, probably SSL certs for ESMTP, etc.  Without all of this, you'll either end up being a source of spam and having your IP/domain black listed, or at the very least you'll have problems not being flagged as junk by gmail et al.

You may want to run your domain through https://mxtoolbox.com and see what results you get.

Per your comment if you just want to see the final configuration you can look at the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and `/etc/postfix/master.cf` files, or run the `postconf -n` command (which kinda merges the 2 files and shows complete active config)

Comment: Do I really need working internet connected mail server to ONLY CHECK what I choosed in Postfix configuration? Really? Is not exist some file, where is stored my answer?

Comment: @gongarek Ah, you just want to see resulting config, not actually test for delivery and such?

Comment: Yes. Your answer was comprehensive and nice, but does not answer the question

Comment: I don't see any record about `General type of mail configuration` ;(

Comment: @gongarek - you won't.  those choices simply generate a config from a template.  You could perhaps `dpkg-reconfigure postfix`